# Check if user input is between two floats - Python

Tags: python, if-statement, floating-point, range

I am currently working on a small project that will take a user input such as "50", and convert it to a float while also placing the decimal to the left, such as "0.50" - This part I have working the way I want, but the issue I am having now that I cant seem to solve is checking if that value is between two other float values. Here is what I have so far.

```
value = float(input("Enter number: "))
value /= 100

if 0.61 <= value <= 69:
    value = value - 0.049 # don't worry about this part
    

elif 0.70 <= value <= 79:
    value = value - 0.10 # don't worry about this part
    


"""
if value >= 0.61:        
    value = value - 0.049

if value >= 0.70:        
    value = value - 1.5
"""
```

When I enter anything above 69, such as 70 or 71 and so on. The program does not seem to realize that I am trying to adjust the value differently compared to as if the input was 65, the program understands what to do just fine. At the bottom is something else I have tried but not getting any luck.

Am I using elif wrong? Why am I unable to get my second if statement to read properly? Or is there a function or something else out there that will let me check if the value is between two float ranges?

I appreciate the efforts.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

welcome to SO.

EDIT:
Solution that should fit with your comment.

```py
value = float(input("Input a number"))

if value >= 0.61 and value <= 0.69:
   #whatever should happen here
   

elif value >= 0.70 and value <= 0.79:
   #whatever you want to happen here
```

---

Do you really need to divide the value by 100, if so then you will never get into the second loop exclusively because the first if statement will be executed when your value is between `0.69 and 69` which is any value it can be if you divide it by 100, therefore it will never go into the second if statement.

If you do want to keep the /100 but execute BOTH statements then you can do it simply by changing the `elif` into and `if` so it also gets executed if the statement is true. This will execute BOTH if statements though.

```py
value = float(input("Input a number"))
value /= 100

if value >= 0.61 and value <= 69:
   #whatever should happen here
   

if value >= 0.70 and value <= 79:
   #whatever you want to happen here
```

This way if the value entered is `70` the outcome will be that both if statements will be executed.

If you can omit the /100 then this code here works and only executes ONE if statement.

```py
value = float(input("Input a number"))

if value >= 61 and value <= 69:
   #whatever should happen here
   

elif value >= 70 and value <= 79:
   #whatever you want to happen here
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response, and apologies if my description was not very clear; im still very new at python. The only problem with getting rid of the /100 is the decimal place. Without that, if the input is 69, the value is 69.0 - When I need the value to be 0.69 so that I can then search between two other floats with a similar decimal place such as 0.65 to 0.70.

Comment: Oh so you want to search between 0.61 and 0.69? If that is the case you can then put the `value /= 100` back and then just change the numbers in the solution I provided to `0.61 etc..`

Comment: Take a look at my answer again, I edited it so you see what I mean.

Comment: Yupp, If between 0.65 and 0.70, do something, but if between 0.71 and 0.81, do something else. And so on. I have started to test numpy and its arange function. But I'm starting to think its probably just easiest to somehow move the decimal point right after the user gives input.  - Just saw your edit, I am going to give that a shot. Thank You

Comment: Update - That worked! Its quite obvious how new I am lol, thank you for the help! I will try to be more detailed and clear the next time I need some help.

Comment: No worries. We all start somewhere. Best of success in your future journey.

Comment: this is wrong. What if the input is 0.695 or 69.5?

Comment: good point, I have not even got that far into testing but I can understand why that would throw me some more issues. May need to check if input was entered correctly. Im looking for standard int (50) as the input. Then the program will convert that 50 to 0.50 in order to check if its between two other floats of the same format.

Comment: Python also allows you to simplify such chained expressions: ```0.61 <= value <= 0.69``` which may be recommended by several linters.